# When clicking on "See more" option on dropdown list. I want the dropdown list to stay open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What is happening in my code is when I'm selecting the "see more" option, I'm removing that option and bringing in the more option to view. What I would like is that everything is done while the dropdown list stays open.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
     
        $('#cd-dropdown').change(function (event) {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == "seeMore") {
        var seeMore = document.getElementById("seeMore");
       seeMore.parentNode.removeChild(seeMore)
       event.preventDefault()   
       var changeClass = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
       for(var i = changeClass.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        changeClass[i].className = "show";
       }
          
      }     
     }); 
    });
```

```css
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
    .show {
     display: block;
    }
    .clearfix {
     padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    select:-moz-focusring { color: transparent;
          text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000; 
    }
    select.custom-dropdown {
     -webkit-appearance: none;  
     -moz-appearance: none;  
     border: solid 1px #087c89 !important;
     color: #087c89;
     font-family:StandardLife-Light_Beta5, Arial, sans-serif;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     font-size: 14px;
     padding: 10px;
     width: 100%;
     cursor: pointer;
     background: #fff url(/resources/custom/customer/images/decoration/smIconArrowRight2Down.gif) no-repeat right center;
     background-size: 40px 37px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <select id="cd-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" name="cd-dropdown" class="custom-dropdown">
          <option value="-1" selected="">Funds in your portfolio (5)</option>
                      <option value="1">Fund 1</option>
          <option value="2">Fund 2</option>
          <option value="3">Fund 3</option>                     
          <option id="seeMore" value="seeMore">View all funds &gt;</option>          
                      <option class="hide" value="4">Fund 4</option>
          <option class="hide" value="5">Fund 5</option>                   
         </select>
```

As you can see I am able to remove the "View all" option and then display the other options but when I click on the view all the drop down goes up and you have to click to get it back down which isn't the best user experience. I've tried preventing the default action but it's no use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Any ideas

Comment: This behaviour isn't possible with a standard `select` control. You would need to use a third party library to replace the `select`/`option` elements with HTML you have more control over, or build your own.

Comment: You may want to break this into two lists or to have a checkbox next to the list for "view all".

Comment: Another option that I would like to explore is that it closes but somehow using JavaScript opens back up automatically after a small delay.